# I think a PPA update broke my system. What can I do?

Tags: package-management, ppa

A few weeks ago I installed `ppa:ricotz/testing` on Ubuntu 11.10. It worked fine then, but since a recent upgrade, trying to launch GTK applications results in lots of cryptic errors.

Can I revert all packages updated by `ppa:ricotz/testing` to the versions in the main Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Assuming the PPA hasn't borked essential components of your system (like network connection, package management, and boot) it should be possible to restore your system to mainline Ubuntu packages.

### Getting into a repair environment

First, get to a command-line. If your system is still usable enough to login and use an Ubuntu session, launch 'Terminal'. If not, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> if you have media keys), and login to the text prompt.

### Resolving package inconsistencies, if any

Now. First, finish any incomplete updates that may have been interrupted.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If this repairs anything, it's possible no further repairs will be necessary; simply skip to the **Finishing up** step below. If nothing is repaired, the package integrity of your system is good, and PPAs may indeed be resposible.

### Installing a PPA removal tool

First install `ppa-purge`...

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

If you're using Ubuntu 10.04, you need to [add lucid-backports to your software sources.](https://askubuntu.com/a/220956/5245)

### Removing potentially damaging PPAs

And then uninstall PPAs from your system like so, replacing `ricotz/testing` with the PPA you want to remove:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing
```

(If you do not know what PPAs you have installed, you can check with `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep ppa`. The PPA names correspond the unique portion of the URLs, such as `ricotz/testing` for `ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu/`)

### Finishing up

Finally, update your system and restart.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Hopefully you will reboot into a fixed Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't seem to use ppa-purge to remove broken PPAs. The PPA fails with a `404 Not Found`, and then I get `Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA`. I guess I'll have to do it manually, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same issue with regards to not being able to purge the ricotz/testing ppa. I resolved it with the following:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-precise.list*
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing
```

Hopefully this will help anyone else having the same problem when deleting a ppa.