# How do I update to Gnome 3.5 on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Im currently on Ubuntu 12.04 x86 with Gnome 3.4 installed. Is there a way to update/upgrade it to the 3.5 branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** Gnome 3.5 is not officially supported in 12.04 and your system/applications may break. *Use at your own risk!*

To update to Gnome 3.5, you need to add these two PPAs:

```
ppa:ricotz/testing
ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Then run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

If something goes wrong, please refer to this question:

- [I think a PPA update broke my system. What can I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76932/i-think-a-ppa-update-broke-my-system-what-can-i-do)

Comment: Is there a way to install 2 gmome-shells in 1 system and then pick which one i want from the lightdm login screen?

Comment: No, unfortunately not -- you can either keep the stock Gnome or update to the PPA one.

Comment: @AKLP: not unless you are willing to compile from source.

Comment: @RolandTaylor: how does compiling from unmodified source allow you to choose between two different Gnome point versions?

Comment: @izx: It was possible using previous versions of Gnome and there is a question on the site explaining how to do it (I'm not looking it up right now, sorry). It's possible because compiling from source using jhbuild allows you to have separate installs of Gnome (different versions) and even choose which one at login by creating a custom session for the later version.

Comment: @RolandTaylor: Thanks, that's fascinating, I didn't know that. If you could link the question *if/when you have the time*, I'd appreciate it.